# Why does not the menu links?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

Can you tell me please which is why the menu links not working?

**CODE HTML:**

```
<header id="masthead" class="navbar navbar-default" role="banner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="width: 674px; margin-left: 260px;">
<!--            <div class="container-fluid">-->
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/" rel="home">Bagel House</a></h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">

                <!--            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
                <!--                <div class="form-group">-->
                <!--                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">-->
                <!--                </div>-->
                <!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
                <!--            </form>-->

                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

                <div class="menu-ggg-container"><ul id="menu-ggg" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-17 current_page_item menu-item-18"><a href="http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/index.php/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/index.php/news/">News</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7"><a href="http://#">Contact</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-227" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-227"><a href="http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/index.php/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>                
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<!--            </div>-->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</header>
```

I put an image to better understand what I mean links.

[image]

Which may be why it does not work?

It's hidden in a div?

I tried to use `z-index` but unfortunately does not work ...

You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because you have a z-index set to -2 on .navbar-default Change it to something like 10 and you can click the links.

```
.navbar-default {
     background-color: #F8F8F8;
     border-color: #E7E7E7;
     z-index: 10;  <-- change from -2 to 10
}
```

This will fix the problem but you may have to fix the rest of your elements.

The problem when giving a negative index to the container of the nav is that your nav elements on some browsers inherit that z-index. You may need to rework your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use an anchor, try the li onclick:

```
<li onclick="location.href='http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/index.php/about/">About</a></li>
```

Comment: This is a poor solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the z-index from your .navbar-default class and from your navbar-fixed-top class.

You'll also want to set your nav width to 1046px.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the fiddle.
I have used  a stripped down version of your code..

http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/y35b2qfv/

- Removed the div right able the `ul`.
- added the following classes to `ul` : `nav navbar-nav`